# SQL Server Installation - What is the Installation Media Folder?

Tags: sql-server

I am installing SQL Server 2008. I have installed .NET framework 3.5. 
Then I got folder SQL Server 2008 and performed following steps-

1. I clicked configuration Tools.
2. Then I clicked SQL Server Installation Center.
3. I clicked "Installation" hyperlink on left side.
4. Then I clicked "New SQL server stand-alone installation or add features to an existing installation"
5. Then I got a window "Browse for SQL server Installation Media"

Which folder should I choose? Or is there any other method to install SQL Server?

Comment: I just ran into this - the wizard so unhelpful when the folder explorer pops up - thanks for posting this question!

Answer (score 109):

For the `SQL Server 2017 (Developer Edition)` installation, I did the following:

1. Open `SQL Server Installation Center`
2. Click on `Installation`
3. Click on `New SQL Server stand-alone installation or add features to an existing installation`
4. Browse to `C:\SQLServer2017Media\Developer_ENU` and click `OK`

Comment: This worked for me, version SQL Server Express 2017. The path I used is `C:\SQLServer2017Media\ExpressAdv_ENU`

Comment: I ran into same error with 2019 RC1. This solution helped me. I found the required directory under 'C:\SQL2019RC1\RC1\Evaluation_ENU'. Once you set this as your medial library folder under the 'Options' page on the left hand side as the first step before proceeding with installation, you will not face this issue.

Comment: Installed SQL Server 2019 Developer version. Was lost with dialog prompted from step 3 "Select installation media". [This Andy Leonard blog](https://andyleonard.blog/2019/04/one-way-to-extract-sql-server-2017-installation-media) helped me:
1. Downloaded installation package from [SQL Server downloads](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads).
2. Launch downloaded wizard > Select installation type > Download media
3. Right-click on the downloaded file 'SQLServer2019-x64-ENU-Dev.iso (Disc Image File) > Mount
4. Select the mounted drive as installation media.

Comment: For developer edition 2019, SQL Server Installation Center is at `C:\SQL2019\Developer_ENU\SETUP.EXE`

Comment: works for me on 2022 Developer edition.

Answer (score 85):

If you've downloaded SQL from the Microsoft site, rename the file to a zip file and then you can extract the files inside to a folder, then choose that one when you "Browse for SQL server Installation Media"

SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe > SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.zip

7zip will open it (standard Windows zip doesn't work though)

Extract to something like C:\SQLInstallMedia

You will get folders like 1033_enu_lp, resources, x64 and a bunch of files.

Comment: "[...] is not a valid installation folder" - that's what I get when I choose the folder with unzipped files in the "Browse for SQL server Installation Media" dialog.

Comment: You shouldn't need to browse to a particular folder - just use C:\SQLInstallMedia (using the example folder name I used above)

Comment: @MattKemp - just so you know, this doesn't work when using the SQL Server 2012 Express with tools installation file. I tried WinZip, 7Zip & WinRAR and all I get when I extract is an AUTORUN.INF file.

Comment: @RoastBeast I just downloaded that file to test (SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe) and used 7zip and got four folders and 6 files out of it, so it looks like it still works to me. I didn't bother renaming it to a zip, just opened it straight up (7zip context menu > open archive)

Comment: I have sql server 2008 downloaded from Microsoft BizSpark.  
I did as you suggested, but still it doesn't work properly, because when i click "OK" noting hapens. Seems like command prompt window shows on a moment and disappears. I realy don't know what to do. I have no problem when installing express edition, but it has many restrictions.

Comment: Wouldn't the exe unzip itself to the specified path if opened? Why the rename?

Comment: Clicking the exe starts the installer, which unzips files to a temporary location and cleans them up afterward. The zip rename isn't necessary if you open the exe directly with 7zip, but it does help clarify the answer and show that the exe is just a container

Comment: On 2016-02-05 I tried the rename to .zip suggestion on Windows 10 w/SQL Server Express 2012 - and it will not extract.  Yet, what I did was start the install, notice the tmp folder that was created, copied the contents of the folder to another location, and cancelled the install.  The tmp folder was cleaned up.  Then, I went to my saved folder and clicked on setup.exe and it worked.

Comment: Why in the sweet holy hell is it asking for a folder when what it wants is a zip file? What is it about database setup that inspires so much sadism on the part of publishers? And why all these hoops to modify a Microsoft app when you can do the same thing to all other MS apps via add/remove?

Comment: Weirdly-enough, if in Windows, you can choose to uninstall and in the third step or so, you will see the path describing the installation media, explicitly.

Comment: It wants the location of the media, which is usually an ISO that you download from the Microsoft Website. Just mount the ISO (on Windows Server 2016 / Windows 10, you can just double-click or right-click > mount it). It will then show in the file explorer as another drive. Point SQL setup to the root of that drive. There's no need to rename the ISO to zip and download 7-zip to extract it, as it's not a zip, it's an ISO. 7-zip can open it because 7-zip can open ISO files. No need for extraction either, just follow my steps to mount the ISO and you're good to go!

Answer (score 47):

If you are using an executable,

- just run the executable (for example: "en_sql_server_2012_express_edition_with_advanced_services_x64.exe")
- Navigate to the "options" tab
- Copy the "Installation Media Root Directory" (should look something like the below snipping)
- Paste it into the open "Browse for SQL server Installation Media" window

[image]

Save yourself the hastle of renaming and unzipping etc.!

Comment: Rats. I tried this. The Processor Type options are all disabled, like in your screenshot, but on mine, nothing is checked. I clicked to specify the media directory (C:\MSSQL on my PC), but got that familiar (hateful) message, "C:\MSSQL is not a valid installation folder."

Comment: My installation went to C:\SQLServer2016Media, but I couldn't select this to repair from. Instead, I needed to select the folder inside this so for SQL Server 2016 Express:
C:\SQLServer2016Media\ExpressAdv

Comment: @jp2code - what file did you open? Maybe it was some kind of "smart" executable that tries to figure out whether to install 32-bit or 64-bit? Try downloading the x64 file or x32 file directly.

Comment: For me this field is empty

Answer (score 19):

For the SQL Server 2019 (Express Edition) installation, I did the following:

1. Open `SQL Server Installation Center`
2. Click on `Installation`
3. Click on `New SQL Server stand-alone installation or add features to
   an existing installation`
4. Browse to `C:\SQL2019\Express_ENU` and click `OK`

Comment: It depends on which edition you have installed. If the Developer Edition then the directory is C:\SQL2019\Developer_ENU.

Answer (score 6):

While installing SQL Server, it extracts contents to temp folder under C directory. You can copy that folder after extraction finishes and then use that one for browsing

Answer (score 3):

Check in Administration Tools\Services (or type services.msc in the console if you a service named SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS). If you do then it is installed.

From Visual Studio open Server Explorer (menu View\Server Explorer or CTRL + W, L). Right click Data Connections and choose Create New SQL Server Database. After that create tables and stuff...

If you want the Management Studio to manage the server you must download and install it from:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en

Comment: The installation media folder refered to in the question is the CD or ISO with the install files.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this just now with SQL Server 2014 SP1. The installer gave me the exact same problem and I followed suggestions from other answers to this question, but it got me nowhere.

In the end I figured out that I needed to download and install SQL Server 2014 first, and then apply SP1 to it. (doh)

Answer (score 3):

I had to select the folder `C:\SQL2019\Express_ENU` for it to work.

Answer (score 2):

I found this one without any solutions. I am using SQL server 2019.
you can do the following:

1. download the sql server 2019 from [here] https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads
2. open the installer.exe and choose the Download media option
   [image]
3. choose the iso option
   [image]
4. after a while you will get a .iso file extract it in a folder it will give you file like this
   [image]
5. the folder that you had extracted in it is the folder to be chosen hence it is the "Browse for SQL server Installation Media" target

hope that this helps you

Comment: On Server 2016 or Windows 10, you can double-click or right-click > mount to open the ISO in File Explorer. No need to extract the contents

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server 2017

Download and run the installer, you are given 3 options:

1. Basic
2. Custom
3. Download Media  <- pick this one!

   - Select Language
   - Select ISO
   - Set download location
   - Click download
   - Exit installer once finished
4. Extract ISO using your preferred archive utility or mount

Answer (score 1):

For me the Issue was I didn't run the setup as **Administrator**, after running the setup as administrator the message go away and I was prompted to install and continue process.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is about too long setup file name. Change setup.exe parent folder name(short a name). And try it!.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded from https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads

It gave me an iso file (en_sql_server_2017_standard_x64_dvd_11294407.iso)

I had to double click on it and then it gave me an E: drive on my computer.

Then I was able to select the E: drive when it asked for the Installation Media location.