# Add SSIS to existing SQL Server instance

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, installation, program-files

I am trying to add Integration Services an existing SQL Server 2008 instance.

I went to the SQL Server Installation Center and clicked the option to "New installation or add features to an existing installation." 
At this point, a file system window pops up. I am asked to browse for SQL Server 2008 R2 Installation Media.

I tried ***C:Program Files\MicrosoftSQLServer*** but got the error message that it was not accepted as a "valid installation folder." I went deeper into the MicrosoftSQLServer folder and found ***\SetupBootstrap*** but this was not accepted either.
It appears that the only way to proceed is to find the Installation Media Folder but I'm not exactly sure what it's asking for.

How can I find the Installation Media folder? Alternatively, other methods for adding SSIS to an existing instance of SQL Server 2008 are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: I think this article will answer your question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979425/sql-server-installation-what-is-the-installation-media-folder

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To add features to an existing instance go to:

1. Control Panel -> Add remove programs
2. Click the SQL Server instance you want to add features to and click Change. Click the **Add** button in the dialog
3. Browse to the SQL Server installation file (.exe file), and select the **Add features to an existing instance of SQL Server** option.
4. From the features list select the **Integration Services** and finish the installation.

Find more detailed information you can find here: [How to: Add Integration Services to an Existing Instance of SQL Server 2005](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326043%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) it applies to SQL Server 2008 also

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. This does not avoid the problem with finding the installation folder though. The folder that contains setup.exe is not accepted as a valid installation folder.

Comment: You won't be able to add features from the C:Program Files\MicrosoftSQLServer folder. You'll need an installation file. An installation file is not in your installtion folder (most of the time). You may ask for the install file from your colleagues or download your SQL Server version, extract, and  add features.

Comment: Okay, I will try asking people for it. It's helpful to know I may actually not have it.

Comment: :) It's possible, you can also download your SQL Server version from MSFT site e.g.: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1279 and extract files you need (never done this). Or at the final move, install new instance of SQL Server and install Integration services with it

Comment: I was able to ask our software architect for the installation media folder and they provided it. I now have it solved. I wouldn't have known to do this if you hadn't told me that it is not on every computer that has SQL Server.

Comment: I have issue with installing Integration Services in sql server 2014, if possible  can you answer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41106207/2218697).

Comment: Solution no longer works for current version of microsoft/ssms

Answer (score 2):

If you've downloaded SQL from the Microsoft site, rename the file to a zip file and then you can extract the files inside to a folder, then choose that one when you "Browse for SQL server Installation Media"

```
SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe > SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.zip

7zip will open it (standard Windows zip doesn't work though)

Extract to something like C:\SQLInstallMedia

You will get folders like 1033_enu_lp, resources, x64 and a bunch of files.
```

Idea from this article: [SQL Server Installation - What is the Installation Media Folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979425/sql-server-installation-what-is-the-installation-media-folder)

Comment: Thanks @Tanner_Gram. I believe it is already extracted because I see folders like 1033 and x64 in MicrosoftSQLServer. No folder is accepted  as a valid installation folder though. Is there a way to conduct a search for an installation media folder?

Comment: Lets say you downloaded the SQLServer2008R2SP1-KB2528583-x86-ENU file to get SQL 2008 R2 and it won't accept the folder you choose. It is looking for your installation media AKA files to install your chosen option e.g. Upgrade or install.

Right click on the SQLServer2008R2SP1-KB2528583-x86-ENU file, click on extract files (winrar options). This will extract the install file giving you all the files that was compressed.

When SQL 2008 R2 Install Center ask you to choose the folder, select the extracted folder with all the files... problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

See
[SQL Server Installation - What is the Installation Media Folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979425/sql-server-installation-what-is-the-installation-media-folder)

Explains where the installation media is:
In Windows 10:

1. Go to the Installation center: Enter 'Sql Server' into the search box:

[image]

2. Select ' Installation'
   [image]
3. Select 'new sql server installation, or add features'
   [image]
   4)You will be asked to select the installation media folder. Browse and
   select C:\ SqlServerInstallationMedia ( The actual name will depend on
   which server you have installed )
   [image]
   And select the closest to:
   C:\SQLServer2017Media\Developer_ENU

Answer (score 0):

How did you originally install SQL Server 2008 (DVD or download)? That's what the program is asking for. If DVD, pop the DVD in the player, then browse to there. If downloaded, you'll need to extract the files into a folder, then browse to that folder.

Comment: I think it was downloaded - I work for a company and my computer had SQL Server already so I'm not 100% sure. Which files am I trying to extract and where do I find them?

Comment: Ask your company's Tech Support? If it was downloaded, chances are the installtion file was deleted after the installation. You could try downloading it again. If it's licensed, my guess is that your company's Tech Support guy/team/department has a DVD.

Answer (score 0):

It appears like it looks for a file. But It can take folder. Just go to the folder where SQL Server is stored. Click on the folder name itself, And click OK. It will take it. And you are done!

Comment: it appears this question was already solved months ago. Please improve your answer to understand the novelty you are introducing

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply like this:

1.) Download the SQL Server installation package (e.g. SQLEXPADV_etc.exe)

2.) Run the installation (only up until it's done extracting the files and shows you the Planning/Install/Maintenance/etc menu).  Now leave the installer alone

3.) Open explorer, browser to C:\, look for the the latest created folder (will be something like this C:\fae78db1ec127d051abf56)

4.) All your SQL install files are in there, you can point the Add/Remove Components dialog at this folder.