# Installing SSIS Services on existing SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, 64-bit, ssis-2008

I found out when creating SSIS packages that I need to have this SSIS Service installed in order to schedule them from SQL Server Agent.  So with that said I've been trying all over to figure out how to get this service installed without wiping my existing instance.
I've been all over online and no one seems to have the same issues that I'm having or their resolutions aren't helping me out.  Here's what I do so far and the wall that I'm hitting:

- I go to Start/All Programs/Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2/Configuration Tools/SQL Server Installation Center (64-bit)
- When the console opens I click on Installation and then "New installation or add features to an existing installation"
- I then get a pop up that says to "brows for SQL server 2008 R2 Installation media so I point it to my Desktop where the file "SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe" resides and I get an error that says that my desktop "is not a valid installation folder"

Please help me figure this out, I've been racking my brains for days!  The only solutions I've found online for this error are to completely uninstall everything and re-install and that's just not an option.

----- edit -----
I have looked at another link within stack overflow that "may" address my problem.
[Add SSIS to existing SQL Server instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127676/add-ssis-to-existing-sql-server-instance)
It says that I have to get my hands on the "installation media folder" or download it from Microsoft's website.  I can't however find anything on their website besides the "SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe" file that I was referring to later.

----- edit 2 -----
When I try to just use SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe I get to the point where I select my instance and get this 'instance id required but missing' error.  Here's a screenshot
[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127676/add-ssis-to-existing-sql-server-instance

Comment: I have looked at the link above within stack overflow.
It says that I have to get my hands on the "installation media folder" or download it from Microsoft's website. I can't however find anything on their website besides the "SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe" file that I was referring to later.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Giving me same problem. I have tried and proposed the solution. Worked for me, hope will work for you too.
Thanks

Comment: Yeah, it didn't work for me but thank you for your post.  I appreciate your sharing your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Don't go via Start/All Programs/Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2/Configuration Tools/SQL Server Installation Center (64-bit).
Go directly to your installation media "SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe" file, and run it. It will open same panel, that installation center does, but it will not ask for any installation media, and will take you directly to next step.
Hope you go through successfully.
P.S.: You can't update SQL Server 2008R2 installation with SQL 2008 setup files.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  
So I tried this with 'SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe' on my desktop

I get all the way through the steps (apparently there's a character limit in posting so I can't map them all out) and then on the part where I add features to my existing instance there's a popup that says 'There are validation errors on this page.' and a message at the bottom that says 'The Instance ID is required but missing'

I'm just having all kinds of issues with this!  Thanks for your help, does anyone know how to get past this?  I'm at my wits end here...  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share validation error screenshot? This will let us try to solve issue.

Comment: You are using wrong setup file. You're probably using SQL Server 2008 to add additions to SQL Server 2008 R2, which are different. That's why it's showing instance ID issue. You need to download 2008 R2 setup file. Use below link for further details and installers.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/34319722-c58f-4743-93d5-dc0ae6728867/error-installing-sql-server-2008-management-studio-express?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade

Comment: That link is for express edition.  I don't have express installed, I have full blown sql server management studio so I can't seem to find the link for that.  SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2.  I found SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2 SP2 but that said I had all of the features installed already for SP 2.