# Microsoft SQL Server 2016 - Where do I get the installation media?

Tags: sql-server, installation

I have a server running SQL Server 2016 and I am attempting to install new components using "SQL Server Installation Center".

It asks for the installation media which I do not have. This server came pre-configured. It's all fully licenced.

This question tells me how to use it once I have it, but not where to get it to start with:
[SQL Server Installation - What is the Installation Media Folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979425/sql-server-installation-what-is-the-installation-media-folder)

Comment: I've already checked that this is not a duplicate of some similar questions, such as this which I've linked to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979425/sql-server-installation-what-is-the-installation-media-folder  I need to know where to GET the media, not how to use it.

Comment: It may be tempting to see this as a duplicate of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979425/sql-server-installation-what-is-the-installation-media-folder?rq=1 but that question assumes one starts with the media.

Comment: It might help if you add to your question where you got the media for the pre-configured server with SQL Server installed.

Comment: @DanGuzman I do not have the media. Server is a VPS.

Comment: [If you have an MSDN subscription...](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=SQL%20Server%202016)

Comment: @Diado you might want to make that an answer - It might work for others (sadly it doesnt help me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download an evaluation version from MS TechNet
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-sql-server-2016

Use your license when prompt, or it will expire in 180 days.

Comment: Thanks, trying it now. N.B You're now the custodian of an answer which will have to be updated every time MS move that page :)

Comment: That might soon be happening.. hehe! Not sure if you can download SQL 2016 somewhere else on MS website publicly. On MSDN you still can.